# Одиночка. Singleton, не проходит проверку типов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использую python 3.6.

Понадобился "Одиночка", который бы хранил экземпляры в единственном числе по id, но столкнулся с трудностями. Экземпляры не проходят проверку типов, хотя и вроде бы как должны.

То есть метод `__call__` возвращает экземпляр оригинального класса. Это же подтверждается, проверкой с помощью функции `type`.

Но видимо, я что-то не знаю, потому, что `isinstance` не хочет принимать в качестве аргумента классы `Car` и `Tree`.

Как правильно написать синглтон с помощью декоратора, чтобы он проходил проверку типов?

```
class Singleton:

    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.__cls = cls
        self.__instances = []
        print("был вызван конструктор")

    def __call__(self, idt, *args, **kwargs):
        for instance in self.__instances:
            if instance.idt == idt:
                return instance
        else:
            inst = self.__cls(idt=idt, *args, **kwargs)
            self.__instances.append(inst)
            return inst



@Singleton
class Car:
    def __init__(self, *, idt: int):
        self.idt = idt

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Car {self.idt}."


@Singleton
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, *, idt: int):
        self.idt = idt

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tree {self.idt}."


class Paper:
    def __init__(self, *, idt: int):
        self.idt = idt

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Tree {self.idt}."


car = Car(idt=1)
tree = Tree(idt=1)
print(car, tree)

car2 = Car(idt=2)
car3 = Car(idt=1)

tree2 = Tree(idt=2)
tree3 = Tree(idt=3)
car4 = Car(idt=1)

paper = Paper(idt=1)

print(car, car2, car3)
print("Проверка типов: ", type(car), type(tree))
print(type(paper), isinstance(paper, Paper))
print("Проверка на синглтон: ", isinstance(car, Singleton))
print(isinstance(tree, Tree))
print(isinstance(car, Car))
```

Comment: в сторону: в Питоне роль singleton может модуль выполнять. К примеру, `re`, `random` функции опираются на глобальное состояние, к модулю привязанное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас декоратор возвращает объект типа Singleton так как `@Singleton` синтаксис эквивалентен:

```
Car = Singleton(Car)
```

поэтому `isinstance(car, Car)` возвращает `False`. `car` это объект исходного типа Car (до декорации) никакого отношения к объекту `Car` после декорации.

Comment: Да, я это понимаю но проверка на `type(car)` возвращает `__main__.Car`, а метод `Singleton.__call__` возвращает не экземпляр Singleton, а экземпляр обёрнутого класса. Поэтому я не понимаю, по каким причинам isinstance не видит тип.

Comment: Разве с помощью декоратора нет возможности сохранить исходный тип класса?

Comment: @МистерФикс: для вашего декоратора важен `__init__` метод, а не `__call_` здесь. Можно, конечно, сохранить тип класса `decorator: lambda cls: cls`. Обычно cache в `__new__` методе прописывают (метод, который экземпляр создаёт), а чтобы добавить `__new__` метод в каждый класс добавить, можно metaclass использовать (объект за создание класса ответственный).

Comment: Но __init__, же не создаёт никаких экземляров, кроме экземпляра самого Singleton, причём в единственном числе, для каждой обёртки.

Comment: @МистерФикс: вот поэтому `Car = Singleton(Car)` ведёт к  тому, что истинно `isinstance(Car, Singleton)`

Comment: Да, вы правы, сам класс `Car`, свой тип потерял, но экземпляры класса `Car`, тип `Car`сохранили. Занятно получается.

Comment: А каким способом, тогда проверять экземпляры Car на тип Car?

Comment: @МистерФикс: в зависимости от ситуации: 1- посмотрите могут ли работать функцию (на уровне модуля) в вашем случае (которые внутри один экземпляр/cache используют, примеры:  `random.random()`, `re.match()` 2- задайте вопрос о вашей задаче в целом (что вы пытаетесь получить: реализовать flyweight шаблон -- что вы хотите достичь в вашем случае). Стоит упомянуть, что многие Gang of Four patterns уже на уровне языка в Питоне реализованы -- не стоит декорации разводить. 3- как я упомянул, можно Car.__new__ определить прямо или с помощью metaclass, чтобы cache включить.

Comment: Я просто хотел сделать синглтон, который бы сохранял тип. Да, метакласс это решение, просто декоратор выглядит лучше и не конфликтует с другими метаклассами. Похоже единственный выход здесь, это вывести переменную `__cls` наружу, и проверять по ней. Однако это выглядит достаточно костыльно, и можно запутаться, если не смотреть код класса.

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста свой ответ, и я его отмечу. Он правильный, просто не совсем понятный.